# outPutText not being updated when a commndButton is pressed

Tags: jsf-2, commandbutton

im working on a JSF 2.0 project on TomEE server. i have a problem on a JSF view, im trying to update an outPutText when a button is clicked, but it is not working.

here's the form of the xhtml view:

```
<h:form>
  <h:outputText style="width: 600px;" styleClass="infoVista" value="#   {mensajes.BloqueoMaestra}" />

        <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{procesar.procesarPeticion()}" update="mensaje"  value="Buscar Bloqueos">
            <f:param name="proceso" value="bloqueo" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <h:outputText rendered="true" value="#{procesar.respuesta}" id="mensaje" />

</h:form>
```

And here is the Bean proccesing the view:

```
  @Named("procesar")
  @ViewScoped 

  public class procesarOpcion {

  String respuesta = "";

  public procesarOpcion(){

  }

  public String getRespuesta() {
    return respuesta;
  }

  public String procesarPeticion(){

   String proceso = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("proceso");

   if (proceso.equals("bloqueo")){
      respuesta = "Update this ";
   } 

   }
```

Evething is working, the method procesarPeticion() is being called and the variable respuesta is filled but the view is not updating when i press the Commandbutton.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you try update=":mensaje". What is the absoulte id of outputText ?

Comment: did you check with firebug what's happening with the ajax request? any errors? does the ajax response contains the old value?

Comment: Doesnt work with the absoulte id update=":mensaje", nothing happens.